# Work on or work with?

Tags: prepositions

when you enter and edit data in databases, do you say that you work ON databases or you work WITH databases ?

Comment: I find this: “You handled it real well,” he said to the President.Voyles knows he’s vulnerable. I smell blood. We’ll go to work on him with the press.”

Answer (score 4):

When you are editing the data you are working **on** the data. Where you use data for your own purposes, without actually changing the data, you are working **with** data.

When it comes to databases as the subject I expect that same would apply. That said, to my ear, "I work on databases" sounds wrong, whereas "I work with databases", "I'm currently working on 3 databases" and "I'm currently working with 3 databases" all sound fine.

Comment: I think your semantic distinction is a fine point that probably wouldn't even be *recognised* by most people, let alone consciously applied consistently. But if it works for you...

Comment: Question to Andy T.: I am entering and editing data in a database. This means that work ON goes only with Present Continuous ? then, how should I say in a cover letter that "my work on the databases of xxx institution have provided me with an understanding of the technology-driven information environmen ?

Comment: @NAN - As far as *work on* goes: the phrase you have written in your comment above sounds perfect. It should however be *has* rather than *have* because work is singular, and environment is missing the *t* off the end. So the sentence should be "My work on the databases of xxx institution has provided me with an understanding of the technology-driven information environment."

Answer (score 0):

If the context for this question is that you are writing your CV, then you might want to say something like "maintained student database."  "Worked" is such a bland word.  If you choose a verb with more specific meaning, you can be more succinct AND more precise.  Or you could say, "responsible for maintaining customer database."